# Same Logical Path for Multiple Instances of ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am running two instances of CF9. Both instances have a Logical Path called `SharedCode` mapped under `Mappings` that point to two different directories. However, when I reference the mapping from the second instance, it points to the directory mapped in the first (default) instance.

The mappings are like so:

```
Default instance: SharedCode --> D:\Websites\SharedCode
Second instance: SharedCode --> D:\Websites\CF2\SharedCode
```

My code to reference the mapping as such: `SharedCode\cfc\foo.cfm`. If I run `expandPath('\SharedCode'\)` in the second instance, it outputs `D:\Websites\SharedCode\`

After some investigation, it looks as though ColdFusion does not allow mappings with the same Logical Path in separate instances. Is this true, and is there a solution that doesn't involve making each Logical Path unique?

Comment: Can you explain your exact set-up more closely?

Comment: @Tomalak: My server(s) setup? I clarified the question a little. Did that help?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the code running in your second instance isn't actually connected to the second instance. You can check by dumping the server scope in each instance and see if they reference the same root directory. If they are the same, you'll need to use the Web Server Configuration tool to configure your web sites to use the correct CF instances.

Comment: I checked the server scope and that is the issue. However, I already used WSConfig to configure the website to use the second CF instance. For good measure, I removed it and added it back. Same thing.

Comment: Try stopping both instances' services, then start just the second instance's service to see if it picks up the correct mapping. Then start the first service up again.

Comment: That didn't work. Only running the second instance returned an error when trying to access the site. So what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I fixed this by deleting the instance and recreating it. Also, these two threads helped http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:63748 & http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:63778